# Measure-Object usage

Tags: powershell

When I use the command

```
Get-Content $file | Measure-Object –Line
```

the result is

```
Lines Words Characters Property
----- ----- ---------- --------
  516
```

but I only need the lines in my output, how can I assign the line value to a variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$lines = (Get-Content $file | Measure-Object -Line).Lines
```